# Move TextView on ImageView?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have to draw text annotations on Image. It should also have choice of moving the text over the Image. Is it possible to move the text by using the Canvas? I searched google and found a suggestion to use a TextView on ImageView and take a screenshot. But when I move the TextView, it is not proper. I mean if I touch the textview, then it is moving somewhere, it is not being exactly below the finger.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, is to create a custom view and set a bitmap with Your picture to canvas:

```
     canvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, new Rect(0,0,100,100), rectangle, null);
```

and then draw text:

```
     canvas.drawText("Your Text", textX, textY, paint);
```

and in the custom view´s onTouch:

```
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        textX = event.getX();
        textY = event.getY();

    invalidate();

    return true;
      }
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

With that code You are moving only the text. By moving a textView like You described, it depends on the textView´s behavihour how the text is aligned inside the textView.

I cannot test this code for now, but it should give You an idea how to do it